# why does forEach method on Collection and Stream take Function.Identity successfully even if it is not Consumer type?

Tags: lambda, foreach, java-8, java-stream, unary-operator

```
IntStream is = IntStream.of(1,2,3);

IntUnaryOperator un = IntUnaryOperator.identity();

is.forEach(s -> un.applyAsInt(s));
```

forEach method can only take consumer as the argument then how does it compile successfully with applyAsInt man method which returns int?

Can anyone please explain the reason behind this?

Comment: because `is` is a stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because "s -> un.applyAsInt(s)" is a Consumer

Comment: can you please elaborate why it is consumer? because my understanding is applyAsInt is function which takes argument and returns the same argument. the return type is not void

Comment: why do you concern accept here?
Function applyAsInt receive a int then return a int.
So we have a IntConsumer: s -> un.applyAsInt(s).
Your code can be also rewriten: is.forEach(un::applyAsInt)

Comment: ok, it is somewhat confusing because I think I have habit of seeing System.out.print in consumer.

Comment: Got your confusing.
Consumer use method "accept", it receive value then return nothing.
Supplier use method "get", it receive nothing then return object

Comment: thank you for the explanation

Comment: @Twister Just to note that `IntConsumer` doesn't really extend a `Consumer`, its a specialization of the same though and the `IntStream.forEach` accepts a `IntConsumer` rather than a `Consumer`.

Answer (score 3):

The code in question

```
is.forEach(s -> un.applyAsInt(s));
```

can also be represented as :

```
is.forEach(new IntConsumer() {
    @Override
    public void accept(int s) {
        un.applyAsInt(s);  // return type ignored
    }
});
```

which can help you understand that despite `applyAsInt` returning `int`, *the returned value is ignored within `forEach`*.